# Qt5 Poppler - Slow rendering of single PDF page to image

Tags: linux, qt, pdf, qt5, poppler

I'd like to add a PDF viewer to an embedded device I'm currently working on which runs Linux/Qt5 on a Xilinx Zynq SoC. Generally the device is pretty quick and can cope with some decent work load such as plotting a 8192 point plot every 100ms using QCustomPlot.

I came across Poppler/libpoppler and thought it would be perfect to do the task in hand, i.e. show a PDF. I've written some demo code and from this code it takes nearly 1 minute to call poppler's renderToImage() method so that I can convert a PDF to an image to show on the UI.

Has anyone used Poppler-Qt5 and found similar results or a way to speed up? If not, are there any other libraries I should be looking at that integrate nicely with Qt?

Here's a snippet of my demo code:

```
// Load pdf
Poppler::Document* document = Poppler::Document::load("/tmp/test.pdf");
document->setRenderHint(Poppler::Document::Antialiasing);
document->setRenderHint(Poppler::Document::TextAntialiasing);

if (!document || document->isLocked() || document == 0 )
{
    cout << "ERROR" << endl;
}

Poppler::Page* pdfPage = document->page(0);
if (pdfPage == 0)
{
    cout << "ERROR" << endl;
}

// Generate a QImage of the rendered page
QImage image = pdfPage->renderToImage(72.0,72.0,0,0,pdfPage->pageSize().width(),pdfPage->pageSize().height());
if (image.isNull())
{
    cout << "ERROR" << endl;
}

ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
ui->label->show();

// after the usage, the page must be deleted
delete pdfPage;
delete document;
```

Comment: Have you had the chance to try the code in Qt4? I ask because, this delay could be because of the  `pdfPage->pageSize().width()` and `pdfPage->pageSize().height()` or you have an unusual pdf file. I have loaded a 1000 page PDF document using poppler in under a minute, albeit, using Qt4.

Comment: I've not had a chance to try Qt4, as we are already committed to using Qt5 (5.4.1) so going back a version was a no go. Thanks for the heads up though.